# Is there a way to have APEX field values written to a page unescaped

Tags: url, escape

I would like to do this, have escape false...

```
<apex:outputText value="{!myUrlField}" escape="false"/>
```

...when I am using a bracketed call:

```
{!myUrlField}
```

Specifically, this is for writing META tags, for having sharing URLs that may contain ampersands.

When I do this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{!sharingImage}" />
```

An image URL with ampersands is HTMLEntity encoded, and the resulting salesforce image URL does not work.
http://sierra.force.com/actions/servlet/rtaImage?eid=701i0000001Kz4q&feoid=00Ni000000FxwVD&refid=0EMi0000000Dh8N
becomes
http://sierra.force.com/actions/servlet/rtaImage?eid=701i0000001Kz4q&feoid=00Ni000000FxwVD&refid=0EMi0000000Dh8N
Which does not work.

Open to having a better way to do this, I've tried replacing, but the encoding happens when it is written to the page.

Thanks for any ideas or info.

Comment: You'll need to encode the value using Apex (I'm not sure if you can use urlencode or if you'll need to do a custom replace). Then on the HTML page, do a decode using Javascript.

Comment: Here's some more useful info about atob and btoa  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Javascript can use atob and btoa to encode and decode base64 strings.

Comment: Actually for your issue, can't you just use EncodingUtils.urlencode(value)?

Comment: hah, more questions - I don't get this problem - no url encoding happens for me. What does your <apex:page definition look like?

Comment: Note that I am trying to use this for a META tag in particular for Facebook page scraping, so javascript is not going to work.

<apex:page Controller="..." showHeader="FALSE" sidebar="FALSE" standardStylesheets="FALSE" docType="html-5.0" cache="FALSE" title="Take Action Today!" applyHTMLTag="FALSE">

Comment: The call is within a component (sans controller, just passing in attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value to a property in your controller. In your case "myTextField". Then set it as innerHTML from javascript/jQuery on page load. For example if in controller if you have set myTextField as below,

```
myTextField = '<h1>testing HTML content</h1>';
```

In the page you can use it like,

```
document.getElementById("yourPageElementIdHere").innerHTML('{myTextField}');
```

Comment: So {!myTextField} is a field in a campaign, I don't need to set the value. The problem is that the value being set is transformed in a way that does not work for its application.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is not to use the Value but to do it like this:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false">{!myUrlField}</apex:outputText>
```

When you write it as the value weird things happen for seemingly no reason.

Comment: Thanks Cody Beaner, it still seems to write it out escape sadly.

This:
`<apex:outputText escape="false">
<meta property="og:image" content="{!kw_SharingImage}" />
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!kw_SharingImage}">
</apex:outputText>`

Gives me:

`<meta content="http://knowwho-scaction.cs16.force.com/action/servlet/rtaImage?eid=701f000000045eL&amp;feoid=00Nf00000013HM5&amp;refid=0EMf0000000ChW4" property="og:image" />
http://knowwho-scaction.cs16.force.com/action/servlet/rtaImage?eid=701f000000045eL&feoid=00Nf00000013HM5&refid=0EMf0000000ChW4`